# Proper IGBT driver circuit for power inverter

Tags: inverter, driver, igbt

I've examined IGBT driver in inverter in power generator (same model as presented here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3owRSqmz2JQ). Inverter topology is H bridge with two chokes in series with 230V output.

Original single transistor driver circuit is:

[image]

voltage rising edge on transistor gate is:

[image]

falling edge is:

[image]

Then I've made experiment...
after removing diode, like this (equivalent resistance is about 15ohm):

[image]

rising edge is:

[image]

and falling edge is:

[image]

both have steeper slopes (they are better).

**What is the sense of using a circuit with a diode, since a single 15ohm resistor gives better results?**

Comment: *"they are better"* -- are they? There are reasons to select both rising and falling edges, and not always "as fast as possible", or equal. You are showing far too little of the overall system to make a determination about "proper" value.

Comment: Faster rise and fall times lead to higher EMI which may be important: local noise susceptibility? EMC compliance?